# Получить родительский input SuggestView.events('select', ...)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Создаём экземпляр `SuggestView`, слушаем событие `select` (выбор предлагаемого варианта).
Как в обработчике событий корректно поймать родительский input?
Как поймать "некорректно" нашёл:
`event.originalEvent.target._panel._anchor`

Поскольку свойство обозначено как приватное, видимо, не предназначено, чтобы его использовали и оно может "отвалиться" в какой-то момент...

Answer (score 2):

В [документации по `SuggestView`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/SuggestView-docpage/?from=SO#event_detail/event-select) есть описание полей события `select`. Через [метод `Event.get`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Event-docpage/?from=SO#get) события доступен объект `item` — поисковая подсказка, с полями `displayName` и `value`.

Код будет таким:

```
 suggestView.events.add("select", function(e){
        e.get('item').value  
    })
```

И вот ещё сразу пример "пощупать"

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var suggestView1 = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest');
  suggestView1.events.add("select", function(e) {
    console.log(e.get('item').value)
  })

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#suggest {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.header {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<p class="header">Введите начало адреса и выбреите подсказку из списка</p>
<input type="text" id="suggest">
```

Comment: Нужна ссылка на `html` элемент, для которого делался выбор. Т.е. на родительский `input`.

Comment: вам же известно, на каком именно suggestView вы поймали событие, соответственно для него известен и html-элемент (параметр element)

Comment: Конечно, можно фиксировать какой именно suggeseView сработал, но их количество динамически меняется в приложении. Можно ли как-то дотянуться до него из обработчика события select?

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже не получилось добраться до html элемента, через event без использования приватных полей, поэтому я передаю в Listener ссылку на html элемент(input) найденный через jQuery, хотя в дальнейшем у этого элемента переписываются и id и data-blocknumber, но ссылка на элемент остается статичной, что мне и нужно.

```
this.InitiateSuggestView = function (elementId) {

    var suggestViewFrom = new ymaps.SuggestView(elementId);

    var $currentElem = $('#' + elementId);

    suggestViewFrom.events.add("select",
        function (event) {

            var eventIndex = Number.parseInt($currentElem.closest('div.infoBlockCover').attr('data-blocknumber'));

            var city = event.originalEvent.item.value;

            var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(city);

            myGeocoder.then(
                async function (res) {

                    var coordinates = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();

                    var newPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(coordinates,
                        {
                            balloonContent: '<strong>' + city + ' ' + eventIndex + '</strong>'
                        },
                        {
                            preset: 'islands#dotIcon',
                            iconColor: '#735184'
                        },
                        {});

                    myMap.geoObjects.add(newPlacemark);


                },
                function (err) {
                    // обработка ошибки
                    alert('Fatal Error');
                }
            );
        });
};
```